# How does MongoDB Compass implicitly detect the name of a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been working with MongoDB and Nodejs and I use MongoDB Compass to visualize my database. I've pretty new to backend stuff and I've been following tutorials. One thing I've noticed is that MongoDB Compass can automatically figure out the correct name of a collection. That is, I only connect MongoDB to a database called playground and then when I make models for customers and movies I see that collections called movies and customers pop up in MongoDB Compass without explicitly instructing it to. I can't figure out how it does this and I'm really curious. I've searched around a lot and I havent found anything online explaining it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Collections are implicitly created on the MongoDB server when you add data, indexes, or collection options. There's no special magic in Compass; any MongoDB client with appropriate permissions can refresh the list of current collections using the underlying [`listCollections` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) (aka `show collections` in the `mongo` shell). You mention data models, so I'm guessing you might be using an Object-Document Mapping (ODM) framework like Mongoose which sets collection names based on the model.

Comment: If you can edit your question to include an example of one of your models, this would help demystify what you've declared versus what is created on the server.